# VHDL check if string is empty

Tags: vhdl

Can't believe I am asking a new SO question for this.

I have a VHDL entity like this:

```
entity dpram is
    generic(
        DWIDTH  : integer;
        AWIDTH  : integer;
        INIT_FILE : string
    );
    port (
        clk     : in  std_logic;
        we      : in  std_logic;
        a       : in  std_logic_vector(AWIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        d_i     : in  std_logic_vector(DWIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        d_o     : out std_logic_vector(DWIDTH - 1 downto 0);

        dpra    : in  std_logic_vector(AWIDTH - 1 downto 0);
        dpo     : out std_logic_vector(DWIDTH - 1 downto 0)
    );

end dpram;
```

In the architecture, I would like to check whether `INIT_FILE` is empty or not. How would I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the 'length attribute:

`if INIT_FILE'length = 0 then....`

or compare it to a null string:

`if INIT_FILE = "" then`

Note - currently the generic does not have a default, so the user that instantiated this module would have to explicity connect it to an empty string, which may feel like an odd thing to do. For an empty default:

`INIT_FILE : string := ""`